# is there a way i can use a if statement in c++ to say if a string is not eqal to either two names it gives a output , atm im not getting it right

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

```
int main(){

    string name;

    cout << "Insert name" << endl;

    cin >> name;

    if(name != "months" || "years"){

        cout << "Please only insert 'years' or 'months'" << endl;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You `if` statement needs to be:

```
if(name != "months" && name != "years")
{
  cout << "Please only insert 'years' or 'months'" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add "name !="

Hence,

```
int main(){

string name;

cout << "Insert name" << endl;

cin >> name;

if(name != "months" && name != "years"){  // this compares variable name if it's either equal to months or years

    cout << "Please only insert 'years' or 'months'" << endl;

}
```

Comment: This condition will always be true though.

Comment: `name` is guaranteed to be not equal to one or the other.  You need to rethink that statement.

Comment: You need to use `&&` instead of `||`

Comment: That's better, but your answer still says "just add `name !=`. You should edit that too.